# .yarnrc private registry authentication with username and password

Tags: yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2, yarn-v2, .npmrc

[The instructions](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/migration#update-your-configuration-to-the-new-settings) on how to migrate to Yarn 2 are unclear, and it's not obvious how to authenticate to a private registry which uses a username and password.

Here's the contents of my `.npmrc` file:

```
registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<private-path>/registry/
always-auth=true

//pkgs.dev.azure.com/<private-path>/registry/:username=${NPM_USER}
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/<private-path>/registry/:_password=${NPM_TOKEN}
```

[The documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc#npmAuthToken) for `.yarnrc.yml` only mentions how to deal with a token, but doesn't mention anything about a username. I've also tried using `npmAuthIdent`, but I don't know the correct syntax.

How can I authenticate with my private registry using yarn 2? For the moment I've had to downgrade back to yarn 1, so that I can use the npmrc file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What worked for me was to encode the username and password to base64, and then use the result string as the npmAuthIdent field :

That means for instance :

`"myName:myPassword"` to base64 => `"bXlOYW1lOm15UGFzc3dvcmQ="`

So in you `.yarnrc.yml` you'll  have :

```
npmRegistryServer: "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<private-path>/registry/"
npmAlwaysAuth: true
npmAuthIdent: "bXlOYW1lOm15UGFzc3dvcmQ="
```

You can convert `myName:myPassword` to base64 with:

```
echo -n 'myName:myPassword' | base64
```